# Why I need C header files?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, header, makefile

It is a dumb question, I admit. Code will explain it better. Got these files:

hello.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(char * s)
{
    printf("hello, %s\n", s);
}
```

main.c:

```
int main()
{
    hello("world!");
    return 0;
}
```

makefile:

```
test : main.o hello.o
    gcc -o test main.o hello.o

main.o : main.c
    gcc -c main.c

hello.o : hello.c
    gcc -c hello.c

.PHONY : clean
clean :
    -rm test
    -rm main.o
    -rm hello.o
```

I can just "make" and "./test" it and it works.
Shouldn't I need to include something like hello.h in main.c just so the compiler knows the function prototype?

I didn't even include hello.c anywhere and it just works! How come main.c knows about the hello function?

If that works, when do I need .h files? I am new to C programming but I thought this concept was easy to grasp, now I am completely confused.

Comment: C ever so nicely guesses at them (usually wrongly) if you don't specify.

Comment: Yes you did include hello.c, it's right there in the build rules of the Makefile.

Comment: Yeah, you SHOULD include the .h, to declare `hello`, but, depending on compiler options, you're not required to.  It's best to not rely on the "courtesy" of the compiler, though.

Comment: @VictorZamanian he means #include "hello.c"

Comment: This should not compile if you treat warnings as errors -Werror

Comment: Karthik - why would he mean that? You don't include .c files.

Comment: @KarthikT - I think he means `#include "hello.h"`.

Comment: @VictorZamanian "I didn't even include hello.c " Ofcourse he should be including .h files instead but there is nothing stoping you from trying to include .c files (besides good sense), and what he is talking about is doing either of them in code, not compilation.

Comment: I asked about including the .h file because that's what I thought I would need to, but since I didn't even write the .h file I warned that I didn't included the .c file which is the only one I got.

Answer (score 13):

If you use the `-Wall` flag (and one should *always* use it, along with `-Werror -Wextra`), then you'd get the following message:

```
main.c: In function 'main':
main.c:3: warning: implicit declaration of function 'hello'
```

And the compiler effectively "guesses" what to do, which can lead to disaster in many circumstances.

Correctly using header files avoids this sort of warning.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. The compiler refused to compile main.c when I used those flags.

Answer (score 5):

You do not need header files; instead, your functions need *prototypes*. When you call `hello` passing it `"world"`, C figures out that you are calling a one-argument function taking `char*`, and does everything right. This will not work, however, if the function takes a float, and you decide to ass it an  `int` (try it, it is very instructive). For reasons of backward compatibility C will let you call functions without prototypes, but it is dangerous. For example, in case of your call of `hello`, the compiler thinks that you are calling a function returning an `int`. Technically, you are invoking undefined behavior, so your program works by accident.

Headers happen to provide the most convenient way to supply prototypes, but you can supply them in the code itself, like this:

```
void hello(char*);

int main()
{
    hello("world!");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I am doing some experiences with that. It's fun that even if I declare hello(float, char *) in hello.c without including the prototype in main.c, the compiler still compiles but every float I pass becomes 0. It can't deal with the float argument anyway. But if I just include the prototype, C can deal with the arguments normally. This exposes some crazy behavior of the compiler trying to guess things.

Comment: @JohnBozo Right, compiler must have a prototype in order for it to work properly. Calling functions with no prototypes is dangerous, as you could verify by experimenting with `float`s.